# Correct way to map DTOs for complex pages

Tags: model-view-controller, automapper, dto

I have an MVC app and I have started to use DTOs exclusively to send data to views.  I am using AutoMapper in order to ease this process.

Imagine I have a Customer that has many Orders.  To display a simple customer overview page I can use AutoMapper with a simple DTO class that maps the Customer name, address etc.  To map the orders I can AutoMapper a List<> of Customer.Orders to a more simple List<CustomerOrderDTO>.

I am now stuck on pages where I want both in the same view.  Perhaps a simple headline with the customer name and phone number, then a list of orders.  In some cases partials are the perfect solution, but not all.

So my question is how a DTO for a page such as this should look, and how that should be mapped (preferably using AutoMapper).  In my research so far, I can't see how AutoMapper can map embedded enumerables like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you create your mappings, ignore the collections/enumerables and just map simple objects to simple objects, for example `CreateMap<Order, CustomerOrderDTO>()`

when you execute the mapping, you can use collections and AutoMapper will just do the right thing, for example `Map<IEnumerable<Order>, IEnumerable<CustomerOrderDTO>>()`

if you're mapping an object contains the collection, for example `Customer` to `CustomerDTO`, where each one has it's collection of orders, as long as you've done `CreateMap` for the customer objects and `CreateMap` for the `Order` objects, the enumerable will just map automatically, unless you specifically set it to be ignored in the customer mapping.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go.  I was missing how it mapped collections that were contained within the object, but from what you say it is just a case of creating both mappings first.